# Where are located a iOS Unit Test coverage results files?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I have executed a suite of tests on Unit Test bundle from Xcode with a code coverage option enabled.

**Question:** Where are located a coverage result files on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find xcresult containing Xcode Test coverage of your project **DerivedData**

For Example

**/Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/********/Logs/Test/Test-YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-2020.06.08_16-41-38-+0900.xcresult**

Comment: So then it's not possible to see the test results in Xcode itself?